# How can I quickly set focus to the search field using the keyboard only in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Pressing ctrl+k in Firefox brings focus to the search field in the upper right corner. Is there a similar key combination in Chrome? If not, what is the best known approximation in terms of apps or plugins or other solutions?

Edit: My goal is to be able to do fast searches in Wikipedia.

Comment: Please confirm my Answer if I helped you to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F6</kbd> is used to switch between content and omnibar

The following shortcuts are used to jump to the omnibar.
Highlights current webpage URI if any.

**Windows:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

**Linux:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

- [All Windows shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Chrome.html)
- [All Linux shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Chrome.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't help me to search on Wikipedia as Ctrl+k does in Firefox. Or if it does, it is not clear to me how.

Comment: You can right click on a site-specific search such as the leo.org or wikipedia search and add it as bookmark. Then you can choose a keyword and you can search using this keyword. For example when you use "wiki" as keyboard you could just type "wiki television" to get the wikipedia article for "television"

Answer (score 0):

F6 in chrome sends control to the omnibar, seeing as Chrome does not have a seperate search bar.